# Why do I get "(error) ERR unknown command: redis-cli" when in the REDIS console?

Tags: redis

I am trying to delete some keys but cannot execute any redis-cli commands:

```
redis-cli --scan --patter 'assetInfo*' | xargs redis-cli del
```

The error is:

```
(error) ERR unknown command: redis-cli
```

I am using REDIS version 3.2.7.  Does this version not support redis-cli?

What gives?

Update:  When I do this without 'redis-cli' I get this:

```
Azure Redis Health Dev:0>--scan --pattern 'spout*' | xargs redis-cli del
ERR unknown command: --scan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is a Redis error, which means you're already connected (and probably inside the cli). `redis-cli` is a command line (i.e. shell) utility for opening a connection to Redis and running commands.

P.S. your `--pattern` switch is missing an "n"

Comment: OK, so what should I type?

Comment: You should type `redis-cli --scan --pattern 'assertInfo*' | xargs redis-cli del` in your **terminal prompt**

Comment: Hmmm... That "console" that you mention, what is it exactly?

Comment: We are in azure, so it has a console where we can execute commands.  Also, we use RedisDesktopManager (buggy) and it has a console.  I want to know if there is a different command line for redis-cli somewhere or can I just use the basic console?  Is this a version thing?  I see redis-cli all over the web but I am not sure where to execute those commands.

Comment: In that case, no, you can't type it there. Use it from the DOS cmd.exe and connect remotely